# Create Operation and view actions with Backpack

Tags: laravel, laravel-backpack

I have the following problem.
We have created an Operation and inserted the related Fields inside.
Unfortunately I can't view any action button, much less insert new ones.
What could be the cause of the problem?

Comment: Hmm... What do you mean by "_I can't view any operations, much less insert new ones_"? I don't understand, I'm afraid. Could you please rephrase?

Comment: When creating the operation, did you follow one of our tutorial here - https://backpackforlaravel.com/docs/4.1/crud-operations#examples-1 ?

Comment: Thanks for your reply and availability.
I try to take a step back.
I created a new Operation and set it stack = 'line'.
I have entered the fields that I am interested in and they are correctly displayed.
What I can't do is see the action buttons. These are not present.
For completeness I tell you that I followed the second example: the one that also includes the interface